# Почему JS срабатывает только при двойном нажатии?

Tags: javascript, html

Почему JS срабатывает только при двойном нажатии?

Задача: определить ячейку таблицы по rows и cells.

Таблица:

```
<table id="my_table">
    <tbody>
    <tr>

            <td>1000</td>
            <td>3000</td>
            <td>5000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td onclick="myFunction(this)">300</td>
            <td onclick="myFunction(this)">400</td>
            <td onclick="myFunction(this)">500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td onclick="myFunction(this)">2</td>
            <td onclick="myFunction(this)">3</td>
            <td onclick="myFunction(this)">500</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

JS

```
 if (!document.getElementsByTagName || !document.createTextNode) return;
var temp;
var rows = document.getElementById('my_table').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].getElementsByTagName('tr');
for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    rows[i].onclick = function() {
        str1=this.rowIndex + 1;      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> задача:определить ячейку таблицы по rows и cells.

Если под этим подразумевается некое получение "координат" ячейки, по которой кликнули, то [можно сделать так](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/rarvLcwz/):

```
var trIndx = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('#my_table tr')),
    td = document.querySelectorAll('#my_table td'),
    out = document.querySelector('output');
[].forEach.call(td, function(el){
    el.addEventListener('click', function(){
        var tr = this.parentNode,
            x = trIndx.indexOf(tr),
            tds = [].slice.call(tr.children),
            y = tds.indexOf(this);
        out.innerHTML = 'X: ' + (x + 1) + ', Y:' + (y + 1);
    }, false);
});
```